# Spring Security Configuration : You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

Could anybody help on this.
I am getting below exception not sure why?

Exception while starting server

> Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or
>   spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring
>   Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2
>   schema.

could anybody help in this please. I am using  3.0.5.RELEASE in Pom.xml and giving spring-security-3.0.xsd in security-context.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
**Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.**
```

Change **schema declaration to 3.2**..because you may be using Spring security 3.2 jar( exception **`..or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2.`**)

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd"
```

Or don't mention the version,it will automatically take the higher version provided.

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd"
```